# POST method with ajax inside a javascript PHP problem

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, onclick

So I have this javascipt code that calculates 8 quiz questions from an html form and returns the total grade. My goal is to present the user with the grade they got, but also save the grade via ajax to php so I can have it saved on my database. Right now My ajax success function is showing up when i hit submit so I'm assuming that the post method is working but my php code is not updating the database..

Currently this is how I am going about it.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
     q1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q1"]:checked').value);
     q2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q2"]:checked').value);
     q3 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q3"]:checked').value);
     q4 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q4"]:checked').value);
     q5 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q5"]:checked').value);
     q6 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q6"]:checked').value);
     q7 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q7"]:checked').value);
     q8 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "q8"]:checked').value);



       result = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + q7 + q8;

    document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
  return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
  } //this ends the submit function

        $.ajax({
          url: 'quiz1.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data : {name: 'result', value: result},
          success: function(data) {
              alert('yay');
            }
    });





</script>
```

And the php code is like so:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("phpbook-vars.inc");
$database="yr1005";
$connect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password);
mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];


$score = isset($_POST['result']);
$query = "INSERT INTO quiz1 (username, quiz1)
VALUES ('anything', '$score)";

if(!mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
  echo "<h2>Error - couldn't save quiz grade</h2>";
  header ("refresh:3; url=hciQ.html");
} else {
  echo "<h2>Thanks your grade was recorded</h2>";
  header ("refresh:3; url=hciQ.html");
}

 ?>
```

Comment: That's because you are just sending what looks like a number. Try changing `data: result,` to `data: {name: 'result', value: result},`

Comment: @Second2None Thank you looks like ajax is doing the right thing now, im notified with my success function. Now its looking like my data is not updated tho, my php seems to be the problem, any ideas?

Comment: If you are using any PHP v7 you should be using mysqli not mysql and using prepared statements: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php when doing SQL you should also run error checks to make sure each stage is doing what you expect.

Comment: Please don't name your PHP files `.inc` -- unless specifically configured otherwise (which most aren't), webservers will not recognise them as PHP files and just serve them up as plain text. This is especially undesirable if these are files that contain things like database credentials.

Comment: @rickdenhaan unfortuntly my schools database requires us to at least thats how we were taught, its open source mariaDB

Comment: Don't get me wrong. It's perfectly fine to have variables and your database connection in an external file that you then include. But please call that file `phpbook-vars.inc.php` (for example) instead of just `phpbook-vars.inc`. If your school requires you to call the file that then you should do it (they probably have a reason for it) but it's bad practice and a security risk (just open http://wherever-your-page-is.com/phpbook-vars.inc in a browser), and you should never do it in real-world projects.